# Soft delete with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soft-delete

I have three models:

**User:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
  scope :active, -> { where(deleted: false) }
end
```

**Post:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy

  scope :active, -> { where(deleted: false) }
end
```

**Comment:**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  scope :active, -> { where(deleted: false) }
end
```

Now, I am doing soft delete for `User` and I have column named `deleted` in all three tables(`User, Post, Comment`)

**User destroy method:**

```
def destroy
  @user = user.find(params[:id])

  if @user.update_attributes(deleted: true)
    @user.posts.each do |post|
      post.comments.update_all(deleted: true)
    end

    @user.posts.update_all(deleted: true)
  end
end
```

The above implementation takes more time when no. of posts and comments are high and it also creates N+1 query problem..

Same as above I have implemented `destroy` method for `Post`, I don't know how to do it efficiently..

I don't want to use any kind of gem.

Please tell me a better way to do soft deletion for these kind of associations..

Comment: Do you really need to delete the posts? You could scope them out instead by including the user model when you retrieve them. Marking all descendants as deleted really isn't necessary.

Comment: A better way would be to use a gem for that: Paranoia (https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia) or ActsAsParanoid (https://github.com/ActsAsParanoid/acts_as_paranoid).

Comment: @gen The poster states he doesn't want to use a gem.

Comment: @Matt: Right, but I would still recommend to use a gem. :) The less code and maintenance, the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to delete the posts? You could scope them out instead by including the user model when you retrieve them. Marking all descendants as deleted really isn't necessary when it can so easily be inferred from the parent.

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
  scope :active, -> { where(deleted: false) }
end
```

Post:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy

  scope :active, -> { joins(:user).merge(User.active) }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is all about efficiency (removing N+1), I would do the below. I am also for "fat-models and skinny-controllers" thing, so I would move your logic from controller to the user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, through: :posts

  scope :active, -> { where(deleted: false) }

  after_save :delete_posts_and_comments, if: :delete_posts?

  private

    def delete_posts?
      deleted_changed? && deleted
    end

    def delete_posts_and_comments
      posts.update_all(deleted: true)
      comments.update_all(deleted: true)
    end
end
```

And of course, you can use the same pattern to undo deletion.

Note! update_all does not trigger any validations or callbacks on the updated entities.